# any available metrics on Cassandra with SAN vs. Cassandra with local storage

Tags: cassandra, local-storage, san

i have read that it is not recommended to use SAN with the Cassandra , which makes it one logical node. hence killing the availability and replication.

Is there any available performance comparison of Cassandra with local storage vs. SAN?

Comment: Yes, they can be found with Google.  Availability and replication is achieved by having _multiple nodes_ in your Cassandra cluster.

Answer (score 2):

The performance of C* with SAN was written about on PlanetCassandra.org: http://planetcassandra.org/blog/impact-of-shared-storage-on-cassandra/

Short answer is don't use a SAN b/c it'll kill performance, stability and availability.